# Obtaining median of a function

Tags: distributions, random-variable, expected-value, median, beta-distribution

I was wondering if it is possible to obtain the *median* for my function called `ps` below?

To be clear, the function `ps` is a proper probability distribution (i.e., integrates to 1) on $[0, 1]$ support that has resulted from applying the Bayes' theorem (`ps` standing for `posterior`). I just was wondering if there is a mathematical (e.g., via expectation) way of getting the median of `ps`?

**R code:**

```
pr = function(x) dbeta(x, 2, 5)
lk = function(x) dbinom(5, 9, x)
mr = integrate(function(x) pr(x)*lk(x), 0, 1)[[1]]
ps = function(x) pr(x)*lk(x) / mr
curve(ps)
```

Comment: A description or mathematical definition of this function would be helpful, especially to those not thoroughly familiar with these functions in `R`.

Comment: @whuber, please forgive my little math background, but the `ps` is a legitimate posterior right?

Comment: @whuber the dbinom function isn't zero almost everywhere. This can easily be solved numerically with two lines of code: x.seq <- seq(0, 1, .001); med <- x.seq[which.min(abs(cumsum(sapply(x.seq, ps)) * .001 - .5))]

Comment: @whuber, the function is a proper probability dist. on [0, 1] support (integrates to 1). I just was wondering if there is a mathematical (e.g., thru expectation) way of getting the median?

Comment: Of course there is: apply the definition.  But if you would like to (greatly) increase your chance of getting a good answer, please phrase your question in a way that doesn't rely on reading the code.

Comment: `ps` is a [Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Median). For most values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, there isn't a closed-form expression for the median. It can be easily computed numerically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your question can be recast mathematically as follows: Suppose $X|θ \sim \text{Binomial}(9,θ)$ and $θ \sim \text{Beta}(2,5)$. What is the posterior median of the distribution of $θ|X=5$?

Basic probability theory tells us that the conditional random variable follows a $\text{Beta}(2+5,5+(9-5))$ distribution. As is noted in the comments, there is typically no closed-form expression readily available for the median of this distribution. You'll instead have to calculate the median numerically which is a simple matter.

Comment: Thanks, out of curiosity, what if the support was [-Inf, Inf] how could we then find the median numerically?

Comment: So you're saying we have a function, $f(x)$ which we want to numerically integrate over the whole real line? The best way to do that (99% of the time) is to define a bounded region as follows: Let $A_M = \{-M, -M + \epsilon, -M + 2\epsilon,\ldots, M - \epsilon, M\}$. Then, calculate $f(x)$ at each point of $A_M$ and take the sum and multiply by $\epsilon$ to get a number $S_M$. Next, increase $M$ and repeat the process. You should see $S_M$ start to converge to some number as $M$ gets large.

Comment: If you want to find the median over the whole real line, you can just adapt the R code I referenced earlier: M=10; ep=.001; x.seq <- seq(-M, M, ep); med <- x.seq[which.min(abs(cumsum(sapply(x.seq, ps)) * ep - .5))]. If M is large enough and ep is small enough, then med should be pretty accurate.